# Capybara, selecting 1st option from dropdown?

Tags: selenium, cucumber, capybara

I've done a search and most of the related google results have returned just in general selecting an element from a dropdown. However the ID's in this case for the elements in the dropdown are dynamically generated unfortunately.

This is for a base test case, so I basically just need to select for example the first one. The text is also the same for the elements in the dropdown (not sure if that helps).

Is there such an example of this?

Im using cucumber with caybara(using selenium driver) integration

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find the first option element and then use the `select_option` method to select it.

For example, if the select list has an id "select_id", you can do:

```
first('#select_id option').select_option
```

As @TomWalpole mentions, this will not wait for the element to appear. It would be safer to do one of the following:

```
first('#select_id option', minimum: 1).select_option
```

or

```
find('#select_id option:first-of-type').select_option
```

Comment: The thing is the ID's for the options in the dropdown are dynamically generated...so I won't know what ID to use. The dropdown itself has a normal static ID if thats what you mean however?

Comment: Yes, the "select_id" is the id of the select list itself (not its options). The CSS-selector `#select_id option` says find an element with id "select_id" and then within that element find the first option element.

Comment: note - by default first won't wait for the element to appear on the page -- you may want to do   first('#select_id option', minimum: 1).select_option if this is the first action after visiting a page

Comment: @TomWalpole, thanks for the tip. I have incorporated it into the answer.

Comment: What ended up working was this btw:
select 'X-test', from: "dropdown-id"

Im not sure why, but I could not get any of the above to work. I think maybe due to some custom dropdowns we had or something weirdly.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can get the first element text then select it by `select` function:

```
first_element = find("#id_of_dropdown > option:nth-child(1)").text
select(first_element, :from => "id_of_dropdown")
```

Answer (score 0):

After two days of searching and reading, this article was amongst one of a few that was helpful. Hopefully, this can help someone else!

I created a few methods like so, excuse the naming..I changed it.

```
def some_dropdown(id, text)
  dropdown = find(id).click
  dropdown.first('option', text: text).select_option
end

def select_form
  within 'content#id' do
    some_dropdown('#id', text)

    click_link_or_button 'Submit'
  end
end
```

I also referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34921509/capybara-cant-find-select-box-for-semantic-ui).

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to select an option from a modal dropdown. After trying all listed methods, and many other from other threads - I totally gave up and instead of using **clicks** or **select_option** just used **keyboard keys**

```
find(:select, "funding").send_keys :enter, :down, :enter
```

In case it still complains - try:

```
find(:select, "funding", visible: false).send_keys :enter, :down, :enter
```

Worked like a charm, selecting first option from a dropdown.