# Capybara can't find select box for Semantic-ui

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, semantic-ui, capybara-webkit

I use **capybara** with **capybara-webkit** and **Semantic-ui**, but it seams that dropdowns doesn't work out of box, because `<select>` element is hidden:

```
# feature_spec.rb
select 'option1', from: 'Options'

$ rspec feature_spec.rb

Capybara::ElementNotFound:
  Unable to find select box "Options"
```

Do you have working solutions for this?

Answer (score 5):

I've created this helper:

```
# for Semantic-ui dropdown
def select_from_dropdown(item_text, options)
  # find dropdown selector
  dropdown = find_field(options[:from], visible: false).first(:xpath,".//..")
  # click on dropdown
  dropdown.click
  # click on menu item
  dropdown.find(".menu .item", :text => item_text).click
end

# in spec
select_from_dropdown 'option1', from: 'Options'
```

I hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this:

```
execute_script('$("#Options").dropdown("set selected", "option1");')
```

execute_script allows you to run scripts in your tests. It uses the semantic-ui method to select the option that you want from the dropdown.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When you post any code, you should describe it so that not only the asker, but the entire community, should be able to understand your code easily.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that code was pretty self-explanatory! Anyway I edited it in case people need it.

Answer (score 0):

After two days of searching and reading, this article was amongst one of a few that was helpful. Hopefully, this can help someone else!

I created a few methods like so, excuse the naming..I changed it.

```
def some_dropdown(id, text)
  dropdown = find(id).click
  dropdown.first('option', text: text).select_option
end

def select_form
  within 'content#id' do
    some_dropdown('#id', text)

    click_link_or_button 'Submit'
  end
end
```

I also referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32890388/capybara-selecting-1st-option-from-dropdown). 
Also try waiting, sleep and visible: false